# Jquery Dialog not loading in aspnet MVC

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

i want to be to display child records when i click a button . The data is displayed as a table.

I have created a partial view that will display the records.

I have created a controller action method to return the partial view.

I have also added javascript code on the main page/view  to call and load the dialog .

Here is the code for the main page/view

```
@model IEnumerable<LearningApp.ViewModel.Requistion>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    @{
        ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    }
</head>
<body>
    <h4>Requistion List</h4>
    <hr />
    <table  class ="table table-bordered"cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" id="RequestGrid">
        <tr>
            <th>Request #</th>
            <th>Date Made</th>
            <th>Employee Name</th>
            <th>Purpose</th>        
            <th>Directorate</th>
            <th>Station</th>

            <th></th>
        </tr>
        @foreach (var r in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>@r.RequestID</td>
                <td>@r.RequestDate</td>
                <td>@r.EmployeeName</td>
                <td>@r.Purpose</td>
                <td>@r.Directorate</td>
                <td>@r.Station</td>
                <td> <button  type="button"class="ids"  value="View Details" data-id="@r.RequestID"> View Details</button></td>
            </tr>
        }
    </table>    

    <div id="dialog" title="View Requistion Details" style="overflow: hidden;">
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js">

        </script>
        <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.8.9/jquery-ui.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <link href="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.8.9/themes/blitzer/jquery-ui.css"
              rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

        <script type="text/javascript">

            $(document).ready(function () {

                $("#dialog").dialog({
                    autoOpen: false,
                    width: 400,
                    modal: true                   
                });

                $('.ids').click(function () {

                    var requestid = $(this).data('id');
                    //alert("You clicked me...again" + requestid)
                    //var productId = $(this).data('id');
                    //alert(requestid)
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "/tblRequistions/GetRequistionDetail",
                        data: '{RequestID: "' + requestid + '" }',
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        dataType: "html",
                        success: function (response) {
                            $('#dialog').html(response);
                            $('#dialog').dialog('open');
                        },
                        failure: function (response) {
                            alert(response.responseText);
                        },
                        error: function (response) {
                            alert(response.responseText);
                        }
                    });
                });

            });
        </script>


</body>

</html>
```

Here is the controller method to return partial view.

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult GetRequistionDetail(int RequestID)

        {
            List<RequistionDetails> listofdetails = new List<RequistionDetails>();
            listofdetails = r.getAllRequistionsDetails(RequestID);
            return PartialView("_details",listofdetails);

        }
```

If  remove the portion of code below from the main view, and i run the page and i click on the button (view details) the ajax call to the controller is made and the correct parameter is passed.

```
 $("#dialog").dialog({
                    autoOpen: false,
                    width: 400,
                    modal: true                   
                });
```

If i leave it, nothing happens(ajax call not made).

I have tried to change autoOpen: True to see whether the dialog can open when the view loads, it does not load.

So i suspect the problem to be with the dialog.

Any reason why the dialog code is not working.?

Ronald

Comment: May not be the only issues, but try changing the ajax data portion to: `data: { RequestID: requestid },`, and the dialog does not have an `open` method defined to use `dialog('open')`.

Comment: I have made the change as suggested. There is also the open method defined in the code. success: function (response) {
                            $('#dialog').html(response); Still no luck yet...
                            $('#dialog').dialog('open');

Comment: Never mind my last part about the open method, I was thinking of something else. can you add `console.log(response)` in the success function to see what the response data contains, if anything? Also see if removing the `contentType` parameter changes anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at this code:

```js
$(function() {
  function getDataById(u, n, tObj) {
    if (n == undefined || isNaN(n)) {
      return false;
    }
    var results = false;
    console.log("AJAX, making request:", u, "ID:", n);
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: u,
      data: {
        RequestID: n
      },
      contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
      dataType: "html",
      success: function(r) {
        results = r;
      },
      error: function(x, s, e) {
        console.log("AJAX", s, e, x);
      }
    });
    if (tObj != undefined) {
      tObj.html(results);
    }
    return results;
  }

  $("#dialog").dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    width: 400,
    modal: true
  });

  $('.ids').click(function() {
    var rHtml = getDataById("/tblRequistions/GetRequistionDetail", $(this).data('id'));
    if (rHtml) {
      $("#dialog").html(rHtml).dialog("open");
    } else {
      // Proof of Concept / Example Data
      $("#dialog").html("**SAMPLE**<br />ID: 1, Date: 12/12/12, Name: Homer Simpson, Request: Donut, Director: Mr. Burns, Location: Plant").dialog("open");
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<h4>Requistion List</h4>
<hr />
<table class="table table-bordered" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" id="RequestGrid">
  <tr>
    <th>Request #</th>
    <th>Date Made</th>
    <th>Employee Name</th>
    <th>Purpose</th>
    <th>Directorate</th>
    <th>Station</th>
    <th></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>12/12/12</td>
    <td>Homer Simpson</td>
    <td>Donut</td>
    <td>Mr. Burns</td>
    <td>Plant</td>
    <td> <button type="button" class="ids" value="View Details" data-id="1"> View Details</button></td>
  </tr>
</table>

<div id="dialog" title="View Requistion Details" style="overflow: hidden;">
</div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.8.9/jquery-ui.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.8.9/themes/blitzer/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

I cannot test with AJAX. So I included Sample Data for the dialog as a proof of concept, yet the script does try to connect to AJAX and shows the error to console.

It's written to be used in a few ways. You can also do this:

```
getDataById("/tblRequistions/GetRequistionDetail", $(this).data('id'), $("#dialog"));
$("#dialog").dialog("open");
```

I don't advise this method. If the AJAX call is slow or details don't return, the dialog could open with no data.

Comment: Hello Twisty, i have tried the code and i get an error message displayed in the console  : TypeError $("#dialog").dialog is not a function.

Comment: The problem was due to conflicting JQuery libs in the  shared. _Layout file. I have removed it and it is now working. Thanks so much.